# java.lang.NullPointerException in HQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a HQL query where i check for certain details by passing a list! an array list to be exact. below is the HQL query.

```
<prop key="GET_HOTEL_TAX_RECORDS">
<![CDATA[
    select
        HotelLevelTax
    from HotelLevelTax ht
    left join ht.hotel as h
    left join ht.tax as t
    where h.id in (:hotelId) and t.id in (:taxId) order by ht.id
]]>
</prop>
```

Below is the code which I use to transfer the two parameter array lists.

```
if(searchCriteria.getHotel().getId() != null && searchCriteria.getTax().getId() != null){
    params.put("hotelId", searchCriteria.getHotel().getId());
    params.put("taxId", searchCriteria.getTax().getId());
}else{
    params.put("hotelId", hotels);
    params.put("taxId", tax);
}

Query k = queryManager.getQuery(GET_HOTEL_TAX_RECORDS, params, em);
```

I get a null pointer exception from the getQuery line for the given parameter! at first runtime the searchCriteria param is null so the else would get executed! I couldn't figure out where the nullpointer exception occurs in here!

Thank you.

Here is my stack trace!

```
    Unable to translate Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at         org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:342)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:266)
at         org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:143)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:705)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:529)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:645)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:92)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(JpaTemplate.java:404)
at $Proxy1043.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.jkcs.khms.persistence.platform.HQLQueryManager.getQuery(HQLQueryManager.java:67)
at com.jkcs.khms.persistence.cashiering.impl.jpa.HotelTaxDaoImpl$1.doInJpa(HotelTaxDaoImpl.java:68)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:184)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:147)
at com.jkcs.khms.persistence.cashiering.impl.jpa.HotelTaxDaoImpl.findTaxByHQL(HotelTaxDaoImpl.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:77)
at com.jkcs.khms.persistence.platform.aspects.PersistenceProfilerAspect.profile(PersistenceProfilerAspect.java:56)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:77)
at com.jkcs.khms.persistence.platform.aspects.PersistenceExceptionTranslatorAspect.invokeAndTranslate(PersistenceExceptionTranslatorAspect.java:65)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy692.findTaxByHQL(Unknown Source)
at com.jkcs.khms.service.internal.HotelTaxServiceImpl.searchHotelTaxByHQL(HotelTaxServiceImpl.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:77)
at com.jkcs.khms.service.platform.aspects.ServiceProfilerAspect.profile(ServiceProfilerAspect.java:56)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:54)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy712.searchHotelTaxByHQL(Unknown Source)
at com.jkcs.khms.service.api.impl.CashieringServiceBean.searchHotelTaxByHQL(CashieringServiceBean.java:256)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
at com.jkcs.khms.service.platform.security.AuthenticationContextInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationContextInterceptor.java:67)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:118)
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.ReplicantsManagerInterceptor.invoke(ReplicantsManagerInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:240)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:210)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessLocalProxy.invoke(StatelessLocalProxy.java:84)
at $Proxy201.searchHotelTaxByHQL(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
at $Proxy1091.searchHotelTaxByHQL(Unknown Source)
at com.jkcs.khms.web.cashiering.hotelTax.HotelTaxAction.performSearch(HotelTaxAction.java:111)
at com.jkcs.khms.web.cashiering.hotelTax.HotelTaxAction.execute(HotelTaxAction.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:184)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.jkcs.khms.web.platform.struts2.json.AerisJSONParamsIntercepter.doIntercept(AerisJSONParamsIntercepter.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:88)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.jkcs.khms.web.platform.struts2.interceptors.PageExceptionFlowInterceptor.doIntercept(PageExceptionFlowInterceptor.java:59)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.jkcs.khms.web.platform.struts2.interceptors.ProfileLoggingInterceptor.intercept(ProfileLoggingInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: can u show stack trace for me

Comment: @PSR : I've added the stack trace.

Comment: Did you breakpoint that line and check that `queryManager != null`?

Comment: When I inspect that line I get the null pointer exception!

Comment: Yes... And what if you inspect `queryManager` alone?

Answer (score 9):

That's because of incorrect query. Defined alias `ht` should be used instead of `HotelLevelTax` in SELECT clause:

```
select ht
from HotelLevelTax ht
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, it can also happen on some syntax errors, like a dangling `)` at the end of a list.